# При регистрации js выводит сообщение об успешной регистрации и при удаче и при неудаче

Tags: javascript, регистрация, response

Респонзе проверяю на дубликат, и стараюсь вывести сообщение о том что почта такая уже есть. При дубликате в ответе содержится ***Duplicate entry '123456@mail.ru' for key 'email'***

Где ошибка? при любом раскладе выводит сообщение об успешной регистрации, при этом в базу не добавляет если дубликат!

````
success: function(response){

if (response === "Duplicate entry") {

$("#msgdiv").hide();
$("#msgdiv").css({'color':'red'});
$("#msgdiv").html("Провал!");
$("#msgdiv").show();

}

else {

$("#msgdiv").hide();
$("#msgdiv").css({'color':'green'});
$("#msgdiv").html("Регистрация прошла успешно!");
$("#msgdiv").show();

setTimeout(function(){
location.reload();
//window.location.href = '../';
},10000);

}

}```
````

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладкой кода

Comment: Строка 'Duplicate entry' не равна строке "Duplicate entry '123456@mail.ru' for key 'email'", поэтому вы всегда попадаете в else. Для проверки наличия подстроки, воспользуйтесь методом `indexOf`

Comment: success: function(response){



if (response.includes(`Duplicate`)) {



$("#msgdiv").hide();
$("#msgdiv").css({'color':'red'});
$("#msgdiv").html("Провал!");
$("#msgdiv").show();



}

else {

$("#msgdiv").hide();
$("#msgdiv").css({'color':'green'});
$("#msgdiv").html("Регистрация прошла успешно!");
$("#msgdiv").show();

setTimeout(function(){
location.reload();
//window.location.href = '../';
},10000);


}



}